# How to force a list to a fixed size?

Tags: python, list

I want to create a list that will contain the last 5 values entered into it.

Here is an example:

```
>>> l = []
>>> l.append('apple')
>>> l.append('orange')
>>> l.append('grape')
>>> l.append('banana')
>>> l.append('mango')
>>> print(l)
['apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'banana', 'mango']
>>> l.append('kiwi')
>>> print(l)  # only 5 items in list
['orange', 'grape', 'banana', 'mango', 'kiwi']
```

So, in Python, is there any way to achieve what is demonstrated above? The variable does not need to be a list, I just used it as an example.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

You might want to use a [collections.deque](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#deque-objects) object with the `maxlen` constructor argument instead:

```
>>> l = collections.deque(maxlen=5)
>>> l.append('apple')
>>> l.append('orange')
>>> l.append('grape')
>>> l.append('banana')
>>> l.append('mango')
>>> print(l)
deque(['apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'banana', 'mango'], maxlen=5)
>>> l.append('kiwi')
>>> print(l)  # only 5 items in list
deque(['orange', 'grape', 'banana', 'mango', 'kiwi'], maxlen=5)
```

Comment: +1, nice -- I was about to suggest subclassing list ala [gnibbler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944708/python-forcing-a-list-to-a-fixed-size/5944763#5944763) but I suspected there might be a pre-built solution.

Comment: How python implement the solution? Does deque pop out left element when new element is added?

Comment: @xiao it is a double ended queue which means you can efficiently add to either end. In fact there is a appendleft method to append to the front of the deque. If a maxlen is present and append/appendleft will go over one item is removed from the other end.

Comment: is there any way to easily remove the 'deque' and 'maxlen=5' from the resulting list so that only the list of values is printed?

Comment: print(list(l)) will just print the contents

Comment: Please notice this solution is slow for copies of large chunks, as it is a doubly linked list, as opposed to a simple `list` which is a c array.

Comment: @Gulzar What do you mean by "copies of large chunks"? At first I thought you meant slicing a large deque, but they don't seem to support slicing.

Comment: @wjandrea I meant [likely, it was 2 years ago] slicing large chunks as you assumed, and this doesn't have to happen via actual slicing. Since a c array doesn't actually slice, it is o(slice-size) vs o(1).

Answer (score 17):

I ran into this same issue... maxlen=5 from deque was NOT a supported option due to access speed / reliability issues.

SIMPLE Solution:

```
l = []
l.append(x)                         # add 'x' to right side of list
l = l[-5:]                          # maxlen=5
```

After you append, just redefine 'l' as the most recent five elements of 'l'.

```
print(l)
```

Call it Done.

For your purposes you could stop right there... but I needed a popleft().  Whereas pop() removes an item from the right where it was just appended... pop(0) removes it from the left:

```
if len(l) == 5:                     # if the length of list 'l' has reached 5 
    right_in_left_out = l.pop(0)    # l.popleft()
else:                               #
    right_in_left_out = None        # return 'None' if not fully populated
```

Hat tip to James at Tradewave.net

No need for class functions or deque.

Further... to append left and pop right:

```
l = []
l.insert(0, x)                      # l.appendleft(x)
l = l[-5:]                          # maxlen=5
```

Would be your appendleft() equivalent should you want to front load your list without using deque

Finally, if you choose to append from the left...

```
if len(l) == 5:                     # if the length of list 'l' has reached 5 
    left_in_right_out = l.pop()     # pop() from right side
else:                               #
    left_in_right_out = None        # return 'None' if not fully populated
```

Comment: Would be interesting to see the performance differences between the solutions mentioned on this page. I like this answer a lot, but I wonder whether I'm missing something here. Why isn't everybody doing it this way?

Answer (score 15):

You could subclass `list`

```
>>> class L(list):
...     def append(self, item):
...         list.append(self, item)
...         if len(self) > 5: del self[0]
... 
>>> l = L()
>>> l.append('apple')
>>> l.append('orange')
>>> l.append('grape')
>>> l.append('banana')
>>> l.append('mango')
>>> print(l)
['apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'banana', 'mango']
>>> l.append('kiwi')
>>> print(l)
['orange', 'grape', 'banana', 'mango', 'kiwi']
>>>
```

Comment: You'd also need to extend the `insert`, `extend` and `setitem` methods (`l[1:1] = range(100)`) for this to be foolproof.

Comment: and maybe need to override `__add__` also

Answer (score 9):

`deque` is slow for random access and does not support slicing. Following on gnibbler's suggestion, I put together a complete `list` subclass.

However, it is designed to "roll" right-to-left only. For example, `insert()` on a "full" list will have no effect.

```
class LimitedList(list):

    # Read-only
    @property
    def maxLen(self):
        return self._maxLen

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._maxLen = kwargs.pop("maxLen")
        list.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def _truncate(self):
        """Called by various methods to reinforce the maximum length."""
        dif = len(self)-self._maxLen
        if dif > 0:
            self[:dif]=[]

    def append(self, x):
        list.append(self, x)
        self._truncate()

    def insert(self, *args):
        list.insert(self, *args)
        self._truncate()

    def extend(self, x):
        list.extend(self, x)
        self._truncate()

    def __setitem__(self, *args):
        list.__setitem__(self, *args)
        self._truncate()

    def __setslice__(self, *args):
        list.__setslice__(self, *args)
        self._truncate()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a capped collection in PyMongo - it's overkill, but it does the job nicely:

```
import pymongo

#create collection
db.createCollection("my_capped_list",{capped:True, max:5})

#do inserts ...

#Read list
l = list(db.my_capped_list.find())
```

Hence any time you call `my_capped_list`, you will retrieve the last 5 elements inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Most often when you need such a kind of facility, you would write a function which takes the list and then returns the last five elements.

```
>>> l = range(10)
>>> l[-5:]
```

But if you really want a custom list, having a cap on five elements, you can override the built-in list and it's methods, you would do something like this, for all it's methods.

```
class fivelist(list):
    def __init__(self, items):
        list.__init__(self, items[-5:])

    def insert(self, i, x):
        list.insert(self, i, x)
        return self[-5:]

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        if i > 4:
           raise IndexError
        return list.__getitem__(self, i)

    def __setitem__(self, i, x):
        if 0<= i <= 4:
          return list.__setitem__(self, i, x)
        else:
          raise IndexError
```

Comment: The reason why I can't use a function that returns part of the list is because the list will over time get VERY large, and it will be holding lots of useless data that will never be used again.

Comment: That can again be controlled by the function. if the grows large, shed the ones at the beginning.

Comment: The `return` in `insert()` is pointless, because `list.insert` is intended to operate in-place.

Answer (score -3):

It can be as simple as the below solution

```
lst = []
arr_size = int(input("Enter the array size "))
while len(lst) != arr_size:
    arr_elem= int(input("Enter the array element "))
    lst.append(arr_elem)

sum_of_elements = sum(lst)

print("Sum is {0}".format(sum_of_elements))
```