# Removing a certain word from a list

Tags: python

I have had to put items into a list but because I did not know how many items it would be I had to set the list up as

```
matching_words=["none"]*100
```

Once all the words have been added, I then want the remaining "none"'s to be removed so the list is only as long as the number of words added is. How can this be done. I tried this

```
newMatching_words=matching_words.remove("ABCDEFG")
print(newMatching_words)
```

This returned

```
None
```

Comment: Doesn't `remove` modify the list in place?

Comment: Forget about C, this is Python! You do not need to define list's length before.

Comment: You just create a list in python and add elements as you go. There is no need to declare its size.

Comment: When ever I have attempted it the result was - matching_words was out of index

Comment: you need to use the `append` method. E.g. `matching_words.append("Something")`

Comment: maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/5944754/2180506

Comment: Also if you do need to remove something. You can use the remove method without having to assign the result to a new variable. Instead you would use `matching_words.remove("Something")` and then you can just `print(matching_words)`

Answer (score 4):

You should have started with an empty list and appended items to it:

```
matching_words = []

for word in source_of_words:
    matching_words.append(word)

print(matching_words)
```

Also, just so you know about the `remove` method:

```
print(matching_words)

matching_words.remove('bar')

print(matching_words)
```

Sample Output:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
['foo', 'baz']
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some things which i want to explain when you need to define list length and when you don't.

> First, you don't need to define list length at the beginning in
>   general case:

You can simply do :

```
#Just for example

new_list=[]

for i in map(chr,range(97,101)):
    new_list.append(i)

print(new_list)
```

output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

> Yes you need to define a empty list when you have another list for
>   index items like this:

```
matching_words=[None]*10

index_list=[4,3,1,2]

for i in zip(list(map(chr,range(97,101))),index_list):
    matching_words.insert(i[1],i[0])

print(matching_words)
```

output:

```
[None, 'c', 'd', None, None, 'b', None, 'a', None, None, None, None, None, None]
['c', 'd', 'b', 'a']
```

In this program we have to insert chracter in that order in which the index_list showing the intergers , so if we try without defining list before then as you can see we are inserting first chr at index 4 which is not there.

In your case if you have second situation then try this to remove rest of none:

```
print([i for i in matching_words if i!='none'])
```

otherwise if you should go with first case.