# Is there a way to set a number of values that can be put in a set in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I started learning python and I'm wondering if there's a way to put a limit of values that can fit into a set and how would I tell the user that said set is full? For example 4 players can only be in one team(set).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force a list to a fixed size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944708/how-to-force-a-list-to-a-fixed-size) (I realize you specifically asked about `set()` but `collections.deque()` might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a new set class that checks for the size before adding.

```
class fixed_set(set):
     def __init__(self,n):
         self.max_size = n
     def add(self,player):
         if len(self)>=self.max_size:
             print("Max size reached")
         else:
             super().add(player)
```

This class will behave exactly as a normal set except when you try to add more than `n` items it will print `"Max size reached"`

for example:

```
x = fixed_set(2)     
x.add(1)
x.add(2)
x.add(3)
print(x)
```

will print

```
Max size reached
fixed_set({1,2})
```

meaning the new element wasn't added

Comment: I'm still confused. I'm relativeley new to python and I don't what do you mean by class.

Comment: You know how to use sets, right? Just copy paste the first code with `class fixed_set` and instead of `set` use fixed_set everything else should work exactly the same. Except when you try to add more than `n` players it will print a message instead.